# Why does this file upload code corrupt my MP3 files?

Tags: ruby, file-upload, upload, sinatra

I have a Sinatra-based project with a [page](https://github.com/dpisarenko/50web/blob/songcontest2/views/songcontest/upload.erb), where the user can upload MP3 file.

```
<h2><%= I18n.t(:home_title) %></h2>
<%= I18n.t(:upload_body_text) %>
<form action="/<%= I18n.locale %>/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>
<input type="file" name="song" size="40">
</p>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="<%= I18n.t(:home_submit) %>">
</div>
</form>
```

The upload is handled by this [route](https://github.com/dpisarenko/50web/blob/songcontest2/routes/songcontest.rb):

```
post "/upload" do 
  File.open('uploads/' + params['song'][:filename], "w") do |f|
    f.write(params['song'][:tempfile].read)
  end
  erb :main
end
```

When the file is uploaded, it's corrupted:

1. The image of the MP3 file in Windows Media Player is distorted.
2. The sound is corrupted (sounds wrong).

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you doing that `File.open` on a Windows box?

Comment: @muistooshort Yes, Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're opening the file in text mode (the default):

```
File.open('uploads/' + params['song'][:filename], "w")
```

but you're writing binary data (an MP3). You need to open the target file in [binary mode](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode):

```
"b"  Binary file mode
     Suppresses EOL <-> CRLF conversion on Windows. And
     sets external encoding to ASCII-8BIT unless explicitly
     specified.
```

or the IO libraries will try to convert EOLs to Windows-style CR-LF pairs:

```
File.open('uploads/' + params['song'][:filename], "wb")
# --------------------------------------------------^
```

Also, you shouldn't use a user-supplied name (`params['song'][:filename]`) as a filename without thoroughly scrubbing it; or better, don't use their name at all, store their name in a database somewhere and use the table's `id` as the filename.